# C# Receive Data from Multiple TCP clients on same server and display it in GUI

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to develop a C# based GUI program to receive the data from multiple TCP clients on a single server. All the clients should listen to the same port on the server and the server accepts the data from multiple clients, divide the receive data and display it in GUI.

I tried this console based program to receive the data from multiple clients on port 4000 on server. But i am not able to connect to the clients. For a single client using the specific ip address and port binding, its working fine. It just waiting for the multiple clients, and do not receive the data from the clients.  Can you tell me the specific solution how to tackle this problem?
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
public class ThreadedTcpSrvr
{
    private TcpListener client;
    public ThreadedTcpSrvr()
    {
        client = new TcpListener(4000);
        client.Start();
        while (true)
        {
        while (!client.Pending())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
       ConnectionThread newconnection = new ConnectionThread();
            newconnection.threadListener = this.client;
            Thread newthread = new Thread(new
                      ThreadStart(newconnection.HandleConnection));
            newthread.Start();}
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        ThreadedTcpSrvr server = new ThreadedTcpSrvr();
    }
}
class ConnectionThread
{
    public TcpListener threadListener;
    private static int connections = 0;

    public void HandleConnection()
    {
        int recv;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        TcpClient client = threadListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
        connections++;
        Console.WriteLine("New client accepted: {0} active connections",
                          connections);
        string welcome = "Welcome to the Server";
        data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
        ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        while (true)
        {
            data = new byte[1024];
            recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            if (recv == 0)
                break;
            ns.Write(data, 0, recv);
        }
        ns.Close();
        client.Close();
        connections--;
        Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected: {0} active connections",
                           connections); }
}
```

P.S. I tried to capture the data through wireshark and i am able to capture the data.

Comment: Please do not combine questions. The two here are _completely_ unrelated to each other; the second part doesn't even have anything to do with networking per se. You should edit this question to remove one of the questions and post that question separately (updating tags as necessary).

Comment: Also, as far as your connection question, please be more specific than "not working". The main thing I see wrong with the code is that it seems likely to spawn far more threads than you actually need. You are in fact dealing with the client-accepting logic incorrectly. But without knowing exactly what problem you are experiencing, and without understanding what specific behavior you were hoping to see instead, it's hard to know exactly what advice to provide (other than to look more closely at existing examples on the web, to find better implementations than this).

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for the reply. I edited my question to be more specific. I can see my clients is sending the data. I capture the packets through Wireshark, but i cannot receive the multiple clients data in my GUI. Its showing, waiting for clients. Any further reply from you would be useful to me and appreciated.